# A cell has 3 inserted lines of data. How to split it into rows for each line of data

Tags: excel, vba

2 lines of dates (it could be anything) in a cell. Need to detect the entries in a cell separated by \n (new line?), and have a function to split the cell for each line entry.

So I imagine somewhere it will detect a character for new line (\n or else) and there it will start to create new cells grabbing the data it detected before the \n

[image]

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: thanks but I haven't written any code. I'm asking how this would be feasible to put it into code. (i'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me). it's a business requirement and I wonder whether it can be a function implemented straight into the Excel installed.

Comment: FYI in a formula you can use `CHAR(10)` to find a line break. You can probably use a combination of `LEFT()`, `MID()` with a `SEARCH()`. What formulas have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*I'm asking how this would be feasible to put it into code.*' is **not** a specific programming problem. Please abide by the [rules and guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) that **you agreed to** when you joined this community.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in `Column A` and you want output by splitting data in `Column C`, following might be helpful:

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitCell()
    Dim lastRow As Long, rowInd As Long, i As Long
    Dim tempArr As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Change Sheet1 to your worksheet

    With ws
        rowInd = 1
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row with data in Column A
        For i = 1 To lastRow    'looping tgrough all the cells in Column A
            tempArr = Split(.Range("A" & i), Chr(10))   'Chr(10) is line break code
            .Range("C" & rowInd).Resize(UBound(tempArr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(tempArr)
            rowInd = rowInd + UBound(tempArr) + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a worksheet formula,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(P$1, CHAR(10), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(P$1))), (ROW(1:1)-1)*LEN(P$1)+1, LEN(P$1)))
```

[image]